# Swift displaying passed data from prepareForSegue

Tags: xcode, swift

Ok, first time I have ever had to ask for help on here, usually I can search and find my answer but not this time.  I have a table that displays a pictures and names.  If one of them are selected it goes to another view and the data passes.  However, I am trying to get that passed information to display in a table like:  `Name: (Passed Info), Age: (Passed Info), Gender: (Passed Info)` etc.  I know the data passes because I can display the info in a label, but I can not figure out how to get it to show in a table.  `Index` issue?  `String` Issue?

This is code that passes the info:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var detailsViewController: DetailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailsViewController
    var horseIndex = appsTableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row
    var selectedHorse = self.horses[horseIndex]
    detailsViewController.horse = selectedHorse
```

This is the code on the controller getting the data where I want the table to display

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

var horse: Herd?


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.horse.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.horse[indexPath.Row]

    return cell
}
```

}

I get an error on the `return self.horse.count` stating not a member and an error on the `self.horse[indexPath.Row]` stating `NSIndex` does not have a member named row.

I feel like I am not unwrapping it properly or something, but I can not figure it out or find an answer in my searches.  If you need more information please let me know and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: change `self.horse.count` to `self.horse?.count ?? 0` and `self.horse[indexPath.Row]` to `self.horse?[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: Is `Herd` a subclass of Array? Or does it have a `count` property you've implemented? The errors are telling you that XCode doesn't find those properties on the `Herd` instance `self.horse`. It's not about optionals (being nil or not), it's about using a custom Type `Herd` that doesn't have the values you're asking for. 

It's a little difficult to understand why the detail viewController has a 2nd table view & expects a `Herd` if you're only passing a single horse row from the previous view.

Comment: @bluedome Thank you for your reply, I made your suggested changes:  on the count I get Herd does not have a member named count on the the index I get Herd does not have a member named subscript.

Comment: @mc01 I should have explained it better.  I have a list of horse (Herd) that shows up fine.  When the user select a horse I want it to go to another table that provides an "About You" page.  It will have information about the horse such as age, gender, breed, resting heart rate, etc.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CLARIFYING...**

You correctly grab `self.horses[horseIndex]` in the segue method, so you've already done the work to get the 1 specific horse. No need to do it again. Is `self.horses` tied to the `Herd` type? Confusing why `Herd` shows up again in the DetailView - you don't seem to need it.

It sounds like what you actually want at this point is a tabular layout of the details of that *single* horse ... Correct? Like going from your entire "Contacts" list to the tabular view of a single contact?

That no longer involves the array of multiple horses, so your use of `Herd?` and `herd.count` aren't necessary. Use static labels or a static tableView to show the info from the 1 Horse.

**WHAT'S YOUR DATA STRUCTURE & WHAT GOES IN DETAIL VIEW?**

Presumably what you want to create (if you haven't already) is a `Horse` Type:

```
class Horse {
       //you could use optional properties here, or require them for a fully initialized Horse.
       let name:String?
       let gender:String?
       let breed:String?
       var age:Int?
       var restingHeartRate:Int?

       init(name:String?, gender:String?, breed:String?, age:Int?, restingHeartRate:Int?) { 
         //set arguments passed in to respective properties of self... 
      } 

       func winTripleCrown() {
         println("\(name!) Wins! Suck on that, Sea Biscuit!")
       }
    }
```

Ensure your `horses` array is declared to only take `Horse` instances, and fill it appropriately:

```
var horses = [Horse]()
let horse1 = Horse(name:"Bob" gender:"male" breed: "Yessir, I am a real horse" age:42 restingHeartRate: 30)
horses.append(horse1)
println(horses.count) //prints "1"
horses[0].winTripleCrown() //prints: "Bob Wins! Suck on that, Sea Biscuit!"
```

Use the `Horse` Type instead of `Herd` in the DetailViewController:

```
var horse: Horse? //nil until set in prepareForSegue
```

Then in the segue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    ...
    detailsViewController.horse = selectedHorse
```

Now, assuming you only put properly created `Horse` instances into the initial array, and there IS one at the selectedIndex, you're guaranteed that the `horse` variable in DetailViewController is a `Horse` instance, and that it's the one selected in the 1st "overall" tableView.

**CREATE THE DETAIL VIEW**

**EASY:**
The easy solution at this point is to create a detailView layout with labels, images, etc and hook them up to @properties in the DetailViewController. Then map the `Horse` properties to the @IBOutlets. Done. No need to mess w/tableViews anymore - just fake it or use a scrollView to make it look like a table.

**TABLEVIEW ROUTE**
But if you want to use a UITableView, then you'd need the delegate methods like you're using... The difference is you need to look at the # of properties of the single `Horse` instance - not anything about the overall list of Horses in a `Herd` or total array.

You COULD hard-code the # of rows if you're certain the # and order of `Horse` properties will always be consistent:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 5 //1 row per property in a `Horse` instance as defined above
}
```

However, if you want to account for more dynamic results (like an array of wins/losses, or a photo gallery of variable length) you'd need to have enough cells to map all the Horse properties. How can you do that with a custom type that isn't an array or dictionary?

In Swift, you can determine how many properties a Type has by creating a ["Mirror" type](http://freecake.yayuhh.com/simple-reflection-in-swift/) and using it for introspection, to reflect info back to you like the `count` property missing above.

```
let horseMirror = reflect(self.horse)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.horseMirror.count //should also return "5" but no longer hard-coded
}
```

And then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can switch on the indexPath to assign the various `Horse` properties to the labels (or images, etc) in the tableView cells. Create custom tableView cell types w/unique identifiers if you want to show different information, or stick w/built-in options:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

   //haven't played w/this to see if the optionals are correct. Consider it psuedocode...
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 1: cell.textLabel.text = self.horse.name?
        case 2: cell.textLabel.text = self.horse.gender?
        case 3: cell.textLabel.text = self.horse.breed?
        case 4: cell.textLabel.text = String(self.horse.age?)
        case 5: cell.textLabel.text = String(self.horse.restingHeartRate?)
        default: cell.textLabel.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, you put a lot of effort into this and I CAN NOT thank you enough....I am on my way now!!!  Again, thank you a ton!!!!